# 401 Unauthorized Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the `jQuery.get()` method

```
$.get('login.php', function(d, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //alert(jqXHR.status)
    var status = jqXHR.status; 
    if((status==200)||(status==202)){
        window.location.href = 'dashboard.html';
    }else if(status==401){
        alert('Error in login details')
    }else{
        alert('Unknown Error')
    }
});
```

It is working fine. When 200 & 202 , It will rediredt to dashboard page. But Other than 200 & 202, It pass the error in console  but doesn't show alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the callback function you have defined is only called when a successful request completes. If the response is anything other than a 200, the request is considered to have errored. To do what you require, you could use the `$.ajax()` method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'login.php', 
    success: function() {
        window.location.assign('dashboard.html');
    }, 
    error: function(xhr) {
        if (xhr.status == 401) {
            alert('Error in login details')
        } else {
            alert('Unknown Error')
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine. But if i get 401, it show unknown error. But console show 401

Answer (score 3):

You need to add in some event handlers for the `fail` state, which will handle 4xx and 5xx errors. The `success` state only handles HTTP codes which indicate a successful request. From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function(data, status) {
  alert( "success - " + status );
})
.done(function(data, status) {
  alert( "second success - " + status );
})
.fail(function(data, status) {
  alert( "error - " + status );
})
.always(function(data, status) {
  alert( "finished - " + status );
});
```

Comment: I don't want add extra event on this. Simply it shows an alert. But alert doesnt come

Comment: `.done`, `.fail` and `.always` aren't extra events, they're part of a new system called "Promises" that jQuery has moved to for handling callbacks on AJAX calls

Comment: Ok how to find here . 401 or some other

Comment: Answer updated with the first 2 parameters in the callback functions. That's explained on the API manual page that I linked to ;-)